# Solution to lots of Emission Materials Causing Noise in the Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light, world

I'm creating a low poly space scene, and I'm using a emission material for the stars.  I knew this would be a problem  because it would create noisy renders, but I thought I would find a solution!  :)

So– is there any way to keep their brightness, but maybe not the noise it causes?  Like a option to limit the reach of their light so I don't need to take so many samples?

I appreciate all help!

Comment: An easy way would be to make the stars **only** visible to the camera, an inverted method of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65032/hide-emission-plane-and-walls-floor-in-render/65035#65035).

Comment: Could you be more specific and add images to illustrate the problem? There are a dozen ways to reduce noise in renders.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that help us understand how you set up your project and textures and render settings.